# Unable to select the text in IE browsers in Ionic frame work

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer, ionic-framework

When I'm trying to select text with the mouse on my website with internet explorer (IE10 and IE11), I just can't figure out why

By default Ionic is disabled text selection. I am overriding ionic classes with following code.

```
       body{     
          -moz-user-select: text;
          -webkit-user-select: text;
          -ms-user-select: text;
          -o-user-select: text;
          user-select: text;
    }
```

It is working for chrome,  firefox and opera, but not working for IE.

Does have anybody an idea how to fix this? I've already search for similar problem but no answer.

Thanks all for answers

Comment: According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#search=user-select), IE should support this, with the `-ms-` prefix. Have you looked in the F12 dev tools? Look at the computed styles for the element you want to select; does the `-ms-user-select` style show up? What does it say it's set to?

Comment: I did see in dev tools (F12), the -ms-user-select shows up. But the text select is not happening.

Thank you Simba for your quick response